# Facing problem while creating database in python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, mysql-connector

```
import mysql.connector
db=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="PP1994an!")
dbcursor=db.cursor()
dbcursor.execute("create database films")
dbcursor.execute("show database")
for i in dbcursor:
    print(i)
```

while running this code I got an error like

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database' at
> line 1

Comment: As Alexander answered your question. "show database" does not exists. In order to debug your query in the future I can advise to run it first on your database before trying it in the code. Makes it easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `SHOW DATABASE`. There is `SHOW DATABASES`, however, which is probably what you want.

Comment: yes that's the mistake i have done it. Thanks.

Comment: If this resolved your problem. Accept the answer!